# math in axes labels for gnuplot (epslatex terminal) not formatted correctly

Tags: latex, gnuplot

Using the following script in gnuplot (v 5.0) to generate a graph

```
set terminal epslatex

unset key

set xlabel "$\zeta$"
set ylabel "$\rho$"

set output "strange_graph.tex"

plot sin(x)

set terminal wxt
set o
```

along with a latex document to include it,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \include{strange_graph}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

the Greek letters rho and zeta do not appear on the axes, and furthermore r has disappeared from the y-axis, leaving "ho".

How do I fix this problem, and what is going on?

(And no, please don't ask me for an image, apparently I don't have enough reputation to upload one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either escape the backslashes, when using double quotes,

```
set xlabel "$\\zeta$"
set ylabel "$\\rho$"
```

or use single quotes

```
set xlabel '$\zeta$'
set ylabel '$\rho$'
```

Comment: Fantastic, but do you know why using double quotes doesn't work?

Comment: It is quite common that `\ ` marks an escape sequence.  For example,  `\n` is a line break, `\t` a tabulated sign,  `\x40` is the ASCII character number 40 in hex (`@`) and so on. The backslash itself therefor is `\\ `.  You'll find this on many programming and scripting languages!  It's more interesting that single quotes disable escape sequences.