# gnuplot: use latex code in macros

Tags: latex, gnuplot

Latex code in macros seems not to work with the terminal `epslatex color standalone`.

For instance,

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set output "latex.tex"
set terminal epslatex color standalone

#macros
set macros
set_xaxis=" set xlabel 'time (units of $(\hbar J)^{-1}$)' ";

@set_xaxis;
plot sin(x)

set output
system('latex latex.tex && dvips latex.dvi && ps2pdf latex.ps && rm latex.aux latex.dvi latex.log latex.ps latex.tex latex-inc.eps')
```

does not produce the axis label correctly, whereas

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set output "latex.tex"
set terminal epslatex color standalone

set xlabel 'time (units of $(\hbar J)^{-1}$)'
plot sin(x)

set output
system('latex latex.tex && dvips latex.dvi && ps2pdf latex.ps && rm latex.aux latex.dvi latex.log latex.ps latex.tex latex-inc.eps')
```

works fine.

Any suggestions on how to make macros with latex code work?

Comment: It's all about correctly escaping the backslashes, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/28964500/2604213

Comment: thank you, Christoph, this solves my problem.